# How do I make a flexible block that will make have the same width and height as a flexible photo and will be on top of the photo?

Tags: html, css

look, i have a photo (1000px). This photo is flexible. It means when the user's window is less than 1000px photo starts reducing in proportion. So, i want to make a block, that will do the same as photo. That block should have `width` and `height` like a photo.

```css
.img_random{
   margin-left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%);
   position: absolute;
   max-width: 1057px;
   width: 95%;
}

.img_random img{
 width: 100%;
}

.block-that-should-be-like-a-photo{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1057px;
  height: 621px;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img_random">
   <img src="https://sun9-14.userapi.com/c857536/v857536576/10ef5e/WDQSe10CrOs.jpg" alt="A random photo">
</div>

<div class="block-that-should-be-like-a-photo"></div>
```

Comment: put the block inside the same div of the photo and it will be easy

Comment: But is there is a way to do this without putting it inside?

Comment: only if you know at least the ratio of the image. If you do I can provide a solution

Comment: Sure. It's `1.7020933977`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that the ratio will always be the same you can consider the following code:

```css
.img_random {
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1057px;
  width: 95%;
}

.img_random img {
  width: 100%;
}

.block-that-should-be-like-a-photo {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1057px;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
.block-that-should-be-like-a-photo:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:48%; /* The ratio of the image*/
}
```

```html
<div class="img_random">
  <img src="https://www.tanianault.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Nault-SunsetOverBaldButte-1000px.jpg" alt="A random photo">
</div>

<div class="block-that-should-be-like-a-photo"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's really works, but how did you find the ratio in persents (48%)?

Comment: @slower. it's `100% * (height/width)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your overlay div inside the same parent as the image and make the overlay take up 100% of the parents space to match the space taken by the image.

```css
.img_random{
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%);
   position: absolute;
   max-width: 1057px;
   width: 95%;
}

.img_random img{
 width: 100%;
}

.block-that-should-be-like-a-photo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_random">
    <img src="https://www.tanianault.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Nault-SunsetOverBaldButte-1000px.jpg" alt="A random photo">
    <div class="block-that-should-be-like-a-photo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But is there is a way to do this without putting it inside?